# trouble with FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response)

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Upon someone clicking a facebook like button, I want to trigger a function.

I am trying to figure out where to put `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response)` And it is not working.

This is where I think it should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () { 
        FB.init({
            appId: '123456789',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfmbl: true
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                SetProfilePicture();
            }
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {
            alert('I CLICKED IT');
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=123456789";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
 </script>
```

But it doesn't fire. I also tried putting `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response)` inside and at the end of $(function () and it works on Chrome but it does not work on Firefox. Firefox says that the variable FB is not defined.